# On a result of Frankl and Wilson

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

In the paper 'Intersection theorems with geometric consequences' (Combinatorica 1981) P. Frankl and R. M. Wilson consider families $\mathcal{F}$ of $k$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with the restriction on mutual intersections: $|A\cap B|-k$ is not divisible by $q$, where $q$ is a fixed prime power, whenever $A\ne B$ are from $\mathcal{F}$. They claim that $|\mathcal{F}|\leqslant \binom{n}{q-1}$, it is cited also by R. L. Graham [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/85_02_euclidean_ramsey.pdf). This bound looks very strange: what if $n=q-1>k$, for example? Or $q-1>n$?

I think that from their proof the following weaker estimate may be obtained: $|\mathcal{F}| \leqslant \sum_{i\leqslant q-1}\binom{n}{i}$.

Now the questions: was there errata, or maybe everything is correct and I miss something? What are current best lower and upper bounds in this question?

Answer (score 3):

The form of the Frankl-Wilson that I know is the following.

**Frankl-Wilson Theorem.** Let $q$ be a prime power and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $k$-sets of an $n$-set such that $|A \cap B| \equiv \lambda_1, \dots,$ or $\lambda_s$ for all distinct $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ and where $\lambda_i \not\equiv k$ for all $i$.  Then $|\mathcal{F}| \leq \binom{n}{s}$.

I believe this form of the theorem also appears in the original paper of Frankl and Wilson.  It seems to me that there is an implicit assumption that each $\lambda_i$ actually does occur as the intersection number of two sets in $\mathcal{F}$.  Otherwise, as you have said, it does not look like the theorem is technically correct.  However, with the additional assumption, I think everything is fine.  For example, with the additional assumption, we have that $s$ is clearly at most $k$, since each set in $\mathcal{F}$ is a $k$-set. 
Therefore, in the situation that $s=q-1$ (by taking the set of $\lambda_i$ to be all elements of $\mathbb{Z} / q\mathbb{Z}$ except $k$), we must also have $k \geq q-1$.  So the situation you describe $n=q-1>k$ is impossible for $s=q-1$.

If we are considering the non-uniform version of the Frankl-Wilson Theorem (where the sets are allowed to have different sizes), then the bound that you prove is indeed the correct one.  For example, see Theorem 1.3 of this [paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/suzuki1.pdf) of Alon, Babai and Suzuki.

Comment: But for small $q$ this theorem gives much worse estimate, about $\binom{n}{k-k/q}$.

Comment: It looks that Alon Babai and Suzuki cite the same paper of Frankl and Wilson, but I do not see it therein, (claim I am talking about is Theorem 2)